# flash as3 that can be used twice not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am having an error in flash when publishing saying i cannot use multiple times as i have two objects that have a link that use this script

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goThere);
function goThere(e:MouseEvent){
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.URL.co.uk/");
    navigateToURL(request);
}
```

am i missing somting major here as im from as2 background and this could be applied multiple times in as2

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it like this and you shouldn't have a problem:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.URL.co.uk/");
    navigateToURL(request);
}, false, 0, true);

myButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.URL2.co.uk/");
    navigateToURL(request);
}, false, 0, true);
```

btw i'm not a fan of anonymous functions but in this case i think it's ok to use them...